# ¿Es posible remover el tag de un componente en Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, angular, typescript

quisiera saber si es posible remover el tag de un componente en angular en el DOM, solo el tag más no su contenido. ya que utilizo una libreria que accede al primer elemento del tbody, lo solucione con css, pero me gustaría saber si esto es posible con Angular 7.

Ejemplo:

```
<tbody>
  <cobertura *ngFor="let cobertura of coberturas; let i = index;"
             [numPar]="i % 2" [cobertura]="cobertura"></cobertura>
</tbody>
```

El componente  contiene lo siguiente:

```
<tr class="tr-resp">
    <td class="tr-deskt">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="4">{{cobertura.nombre}}</td>
</tr>
<tr class="compare-row" [ngClass]="{'trGris': numPar == 0}">
    <td class="tr-deskt">{{cobertura.nombre}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let item of cobertura.producto">
        <span *ngIf="item != null && item != ''" class="tickgreen">✔</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

lo anterior en el dom obtengo:
[image: DOM resultante]

Es posible obtenerlo así ?:
[image: DOM esperado]

Comment: tendrías que reescribir el componente para que use un `selector: '[cobertura]'` y el html queda onda `<tr cobertura></tr>` y así rellena el `tr` con los `td`

Comment: ok, entiendo, ¿como una directiva?

Comment: si, sigue siendo un componente pero lo "invocas como directiva", generalmente se dice un componente es una clase de directiva con una plantilla de view ( no sólo cambia el comportamiento, también provee su propia jerarquía de elementos ) en este caso mete un par de TD con un colspan calculado

Comment: pero este componente tiene inputs:   
<cobertura *ngFor="let cobertura of coberturas; let i = index;"
                              [numPar]="i % 2" [cobertura]="cobertura"></cobertura>

Comment: habría que ver código para una solución específica, si podes agregarlo anonimizado haciendo click en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/250759/edit) vemos como resolverlo

Comment: @aloMalbarez saludos!! Listo, agregue el código y dos capturas.

Answer (score 0):

Si claro,

puedes intentar algo como esto

```html
@ViewChild("idComponente") componente: HTMLElement;

addMyClass(){
  this.renderer.addClass(this.componente.nativeElement, "my-class");
}

removeMyClass(){
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.componente.nativeElement, "my-class");
  }
  
// O ALGO ASI
  
disable(){PRACTICA
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.componente.nativeElement, "disabled", "true");
}

enable(){
   this.renderer.removeAttribute(this.componente.nativeElement, "disabled");
}
```

Comment: Aunque este enlace puede servir para resolver la pregunta, deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle y las partes clave de la página enlazada. Las publicaciones que son básicamente un enlace se consideran de baja calidad porque, si el enlace se rompe, dejan de tener sentido. Lee [answer] para más información.